# How to externally view the PDF file compiled by a remote Linux server on a local Windows system?

Tags: ssh, remote, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm using VS Code to write and compile LaTeX files through the Remote series extensions of VS Code on a Linux server. How can I use an external viewer for the compiled PDF files?

I was thinking of passing the remote PDF file to local SumatraPDF or viewing it on the remote server using Okular(A PDF viewer that supports forward and inverse search. If there is any other viewer that supports F&I search, is acceptable too), and forwarding the window to the local machine using the X server. But I don't know how to set this exactly in LaTeX Workshop. I'd appreciate that if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can [specify the PDF viewer](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View) in LaTeX by setting `latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer`.   The default PDF viewer is just  "tab", but change that to the preferred viewer.

BTW, I find the native Linux Okular a bit slow to open, and not as versatile as some other tools, e.g., [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) or [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) which run well under wine on Linux. If you specify those in a command, prefix the path to the Windows executable with "wine", e.g., `wine /Winapps/pdfxchange/PDFXCview.exe`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I just set the viewer on my local machine like Sumatra, it seems the viewer can not be called by VS Code this way. I guess it's because the local viewer can not access the remote PDF.